SIM800l interfacing with ESP32 Message sending issue
I am using sim800l along with esp32, when I try to send sms it sends particular phone numbers only I do not know where the exact problem arises. On some phones, I cannot see the received text in the message folder, it is hidden under the setting -> SIM CARD MESSAGE option.
i tried with AIRTEL sim.
